# Change font size for "noDataTextDescription" in mpandroidchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How can I change font size, for the following

```
chart.setNoDataTextDescription("There are no readings in selected date range.");
```

I have tried this

```
  Paint p = chart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_INFO);
    p.setTextSize(17);
```

But it doesnt seem to increase the size. This is a line chart. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same question.You should call these in `onResume` or the function that is called after `onResume`, because in `onCreate`, the view hasn't begun to draw.

for example:

```
 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
   ....
   Paint p = chart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_INFO);
   p.setTextSize(17);
   chart.invalidate
   ...
}
```